# Docusign Rest API V2

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the Rest API to send out a document.  We create the envelope and upload the document.  We then redirect the user to the document in a browser.   If the user selects themselves as the First Signer and someone else as the second signer and sends the document, it does not prompt them if they want to sign it now.  If they use the same process in the console it does prompt them to sign.  Is there a way to have it prompt when using the API call?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a feature that's baked into the DocuSign platform when sending signature requests from the Console.  There is no setting to "enable" this in your account, you simply need to write the logic yourself.

You just need to detect who is logged in to your integration/app then if they send a signature request where they are the first recipient (and there's no additional authentication they need to pass such as KBA for instance) then you can have your app pop up a dialog asking if they would like to sign now.  But as mentioned, there's no "setting" in the DocuSign API that would somehow accomplish this in your integration.